# How to show the profile of a ZPolyLine with QGIS 3.26 profile tool

Tags: qgis-3, line, profile

I am trying out the new QGIS 3.26 profile tool. (actually a Linux build of today's master: 2f3d6b, so 3.27)
I imported a SRTM DEM.
I can create a ZPolyLine and use it to plot the Terrain Elevation of the SRTM layer under the line by

1. Ticking the SRTM Layer in the profile widget,
2. Selecting the "Capture Curve from Feature" tool and selecting my ZPolyLine.
   all good so far.

Now I want to add the ZPolyline (The Z values of the ZPolyline are slightly higher that the corresponing SRTM values) itself to the profile. I would expect to just have to tick the ZPolyLine layer in the profile tool. But that doesn't display it.

Am I missing something?

The workaround is to extract the vertices from the ZPolyLine. Ticking the layer with the extracted vertices displays the profile of the vertices, and making it a "Surface" brings the line between the vertices. but there must be something easier right?